# Vue: Component method from vuex module?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I'm using namespaced modules for state management in vuex, I try to keep all my actions mutations inside my modules as this helps me keep most of my code in the same place (modules acting like classes or similar) hoever there's an issue, I'd like to fire a component method to clear a form when a vuex action is successfull (that is the axios request gets an OK/200 response) but sadly I can't fire a methos from vuex module into my component ( there's no this inisde module).

I also tried adding a .then to my action call but it fires right after I call the action...

I guess I could move the action into the component itself but I'd rather not, what do you guys suggest?

My component:

```
stripeSourceHandler: function(sourceId)
    {
        if(this.customerSources.length == 0)
        {
            console.log('createSourceAndCustomer');
            this.createSourceAndCustomer({ id: sourceId });
        }
        else
        {
            console.log('addSource');
            this.addSource({ id: sourceId }).then(alert('Form cleared')); //this fires right after calling addSource
        };
    },
```

My module action:

```
addSource({ commit }, sourceId)
    {
        commit('Loader/SET_LOADER', { status:1, message: 'Procesando...' }, { root: true });
        axios.post('/stripe/add-source', sourceId)
        .then((response) => {
            commit('Loader/SET_LOADER', { status:2, message: response.data.message }, { root: true });
            commit('ADD_SOURCE', response.data.customer);
            //I can't clear component form from this...
        }, 
        (error) => {
            commit('Loader/SET_LOADER', { status:3, errors: error, message: 'Error al añadir el pago.' }, { root: true });
        });
    },
```

Comment: You can't do this because you don't _want_ to do this. Your store should be mapped to your components, never the other way around

Answer (score 0):

Two issues:

- You need to return the promise from the action so that you can use `.then()` to schedule code to be executed once the action has completed (this code being whatever you need to do to clear the form).
- `.then()` takes one (or two) *functions* as parameters which will be called once the promise has resolved, instead you're just calling `alert()` immediately.

It'll be something like:

**Component method**

```es6
stripeSourceHandler(sourceId) {
  if (this.customerSources.length == 0) {
    this.createSourceAndCustomer({ id: sourceId });
  } else {
    this.addSource({ id: sourceId }).then(() => {
      // Clear the form here
      alert('Form cleared');
    });
  }
}
```

**Vuex action**

```es6
addSource({ commit }, sourceId) {
  commit('Loader/SET_LOADER', { status:1, message: 'Procesando...' }, { root: true });

  // Return the promise here
  return axios.post('/stripe/add-source', sourceId)
    .then(response => {
      commit('Loader/SET_LOADER', { status:2, message: response.data.message }, { root: true });
      commit('ADD_SOURCE', response.data.customer);
    }, error => {
      commit('Loader/SET_LOADER', { status:3, errors: error, message: 'Error al añadir el pago.' }, { root: true });
    });
}
```